# During automations tests on Jenkins folder for download isn`t created

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I write automation tests in selenium (java) in maven project. I have defined download folder as:

public static String userDownloadDir =  System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "target" + File.separator + "downloadFiles";

so the folder dowloadFiles appears in target directory each time I download anything.

Also I have assertion in my tests: if after clicking and downloading the directory has appeared in target path.
when I run locally on Windows in IJ it works and assertion returns true(that directory is created) but when I run tests on Jenkins it returns false.

Assertion code:

```
public boolean ifDirExists(){
   File tmpDir = new File(userDownloadDir);
    boolean exists = tmpDir.exists();
    if(exists) {
        logger.info("Directory was successfully created");
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

can anybody help why it returns false? should I change especially path for downloading files for Jenkins or something else is wrong?

Comment: Do you create the directory `target` if it doesn't exist ? Could you add the code that downloads the file please. Also, you should log the path of tmpDir and check if it exists / you have enough privileges

Comment: target already exists, I just create directory downloadFiles.

Answer (score -1):

When you run tests from jenkins, by default jenkins downloads files in location

```
var/lib/jenkins
```

You can then write code to copy files from var/lib/jenkins to other directory.